# Insert timestamp when value paste/edits in whole row in google sheets, only insert to blank cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- I'm trying to insert a timestamp into a cell in the "timestamp" column with the same row index as the edited or pasted value in the "status" column, only insert a timestamp in to an empty cell in "timestamp" column, while skipping the cell that already has a value in the "timestamp" column.
- I'd also like to convert the date to a number, such as yymmddHHmmss*1000 + seri number column "No." Exp: If the timestamp is 22:01:20 14:08:05 and the sequence number in column "No." is 678, then value I want to insert into column "ID" is 2201201408050678.
- I need to use the column header as a reference in this code to ensure that the function works correctly when the column index changes.
- Issue: When changing many rows, this code simply repeats the original function for each selected cell. It gets the job done, but not too quickly.

How can I improve code speed when a multi-row update occurs?

| No. | Timestamp | ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 24:01:22 15:01:30 | 2201241501300020 | Approved |
| 17 |  |  | Process |
| 16 | 24:01:22 15:59:10 | 2201241559100016 | Approved |
| 16 |  |  |  |

```html
function neworder2_onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if ((sheet.getSheetName() == 'RETAIL_ORDER') || (sheet.getSheetName() == 'HAMPER_ORDER') || (sheet.getSheetName() == 'SEA FOOD_ORDER') || (sheet.getSheetName() == 'GARDEN_ORDER'))
  {
  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  var col_header = sheet.getRange(1,col).getValue();
  if (col_header != 'Status') return;

  var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var timestamp_col = headers.indexOf('Timestamp') + 1;
  var num_col = headers.indexOf('No.') + 1;
  var id_col = headers.indexOf('ID') + 1;

  var row_start = e.range.rowStart;
  var row_end = e.range.rowEnd;
  if (sheet.getRange(row_start,col).getValue() != 'Approved') return;

  var tz = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

  for (let row = row_start; row <= row_end; row++) {

    var timestamp_cell = sheet.getRange(row, timestamp_col);
    if (timestamp_cell.getValue() !== '') continue;
    timestamp_cell.setValue(timestamp).setNumberFormat('yy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss');

    var num = sheet.getRange(row,num_col).getValue().toString().padStart(4,'0');
    var id = timestamp.replace(/\D/g,'') + num;
    var id_cell = sheet.getRange(row,id_col);

    id_cell.setValue(id);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your question, your script works fine, and you want to reduce the process cost of the script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike yes, It works fine but if have to change multi row at the same time like 15 more row at the same time, it process to long. I seeking for some way to reduce process cost of the script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misundetstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Your script works fine. You want to reduce the process cost of the script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function neworder2_onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (['RETAIL_ORDER', 'HAMPER_ORDER', 'SEA FOOD_ORDER', 'GARDEN_ORDER'].includes(sheet.getSheetName())) { // Modified
    var col = e.range.columnStart;
    var col_header = sheet.getRange(1, col).getValue();
    if (col_header != 'Status') return;
    var row_start = e.range.rowStart;
    var row_end = e.range.rowEnd;

    // I modified below script.
    var values = sheet.getRange(row_start, 1, row_end - row_start + 1, 4).getValues();
    if (!values.some(r => r[3] == 'Approved')) return;
    var tz = e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    var res = values.map(([a, b, c]) => (a == "" || b != "") ? [b, c] : [timestamp, timestamp.replace(/\D/g, '') + a.toString().padStart(4, '0')]);
    sheet.getRange(row_start, 2, row_end - row_start + 1, 2).setValues(res);
    sheet.getRange(row_start, 2, row_end - row_start + 1, 1).setNumberFormat('yy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss');
  }
}
```

- In this modification, after the array was created using the script in your for loop, the array was put to the sheet.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added 1:

From your following replying,

> When "status", "ID" or "timstamp" column index change, in case I want to insert column then our code not working. Can we use column header (status, timestamp, ID, No.) as pramameter for my cript? Can you give suggestion to do this?

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (['RETAIL_ORDER', 'HAMPER_ORDER', 'SEA FOOD_ORDER', 'GARDEN_ORDER'].includes(sheet.getSheetName())) { // Modified
    var col = e.range.columnStart;
    var header = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].map(h => h.toLowerCase()); // Added
    var obj = header.reduce((o, e, i) => (o[e] = i, o), {});
    var col_header = header[col - 1]; // Modified
    if (col_header != 'status') return;
    var row_start = e.range.rowStart;
    var row_end = e.range.rowEnd;

    // I modified below script.
    var values = sheet.getRange(row_start, 1, row_end - row_start + 1, header.length).getValues();
    if (!values.some(r => r[obj["status"]] == 'Approved')) return;
    var tz = e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    var res = values.map(r => {
      if (!(r[obj["no."]] == "" || r[obj["timestamp"]] != "")) {
        r[obj["timestamp"]] = timestamp;
        r[obj["id"]] = timestamp.replace(/\D/g, '') + r[obj["no."]].toString().padStart(4, '0');
      }
      return r;
    });
    sheet.getRange(row_start, 1, row_end - row_start + 1, res[0].length).setValues(res);
    sheet.getRange(row_start, [obj["timestamp"]] + 1, row_end - row_start + 1).setNumberFormat('yy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss');
  }
}
```

- In this script, from your question, it supposes that the header values are `No.,Timestamp,ID,Status`. Please be careful this.

### Added 2:

From your following new issue,

> It's working but there is some issue with my sheet. when scipt ran that paste value to all column, some of theme using arrayformula so all column use arrayformula will get error "#REF!" Can we just paste value to column timestame, id.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (['RETAIL_ORDER', 'HAMPER_ORDER', 'SEA FOOD_ORDER', 'GARDEN_ORDER'].includes(sheet.getSheetName())) { // Modified
    var col = e.range.columnStart;
    var header = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].map(h => h.toLowerCase()); // Added
    var obj = header.reduce((o, e, i) => (o[e] = i, o), {});
    var col_header = header[col - 1]; // Modified
    if (col_header != 'status') return;
    var row_start = e.range.rowStart;
    var row_end = e.range.rowEnd;

    // I modified below script.
    var values = sheet.getRange(row_start, 1, row_end - row_start + 1, header.length).getValues();
    if (!values.some(r => r[obj["status"]] == 'Approved')) return;
    var tz = e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    var res = values.map(r => {
      if (r[obj["no."]] != "" && r[obj["timestamp"]] == "" && r[obj["status"]] == "Approved") {
        r[obj["timestamp"]] = timestamp;
        r[obj["id"]] = timestamp.replace(/\D/g, '') + r[obj["no."]].toString().padStart(4, '0');
      }
      r.shift();
      return r;
    });
    sheet.getRange(row_start, 2, row_end - row_start + 1, res[0].length).setValues(res);
    sheet.getRange(row_start, [obj["timestamp"]] + 2, row_end - row_start + 1).setNumberFormat('yy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss');
  }
}
```

Comment: When "status", "ID" or "timstamp" column index change, in case I want to insert column then our code not working. Can we use column header (status, timestamp, ID, No.) as pramameter for my cript? Can you give suggestion to do this?

Comment: @brianphamx Thank you for replying. About `When "status", "ID" or "timstamp" column index change, in case I want to insert column then our code not working. Can we use column header (status, timestamp, ID, No.) as pramameter for my cript? Can you give suggestion to do this?`, I couldn't notice. I apologize for my poor English skill. I added one more sample script for your replying. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question again, I apologize again.

Comment: It's working but there is some issue with my sheet. when scipt ran that paste value to all column, some of theme using arrayformula so all column use arrayformula will get error "#REF!" Can we just paste value to column timestame, id. You can Here is my sheet for testing https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kXlH6fnCWLAV8Q-FEiSOXpuUqgCGe0cgLLDd_zLgmaM/edit#gid=978209045

Comment: @brianphamx Thank you for replying. About your new issue, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your new code working but still make column with arrayformula #REF!. Exp: I have column H with arrayformula then when scipt ran they will get #REF!. In final sheet I have many arrayformula column and their ịndex can random change. testing sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kXlH6fnCWLAV8Q-FEiSOXpuUqgCGe0cgLLDd_zLgmaM/edit#gid=978209045